# Is there an open source task runner for Winforms or ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, dialog

Is this available as an open source component anywhere?

If my code behind a Form or Page (winforms or asp.net) does something like this:

```
var pidList = PidsToSynch;
pidList.AsParallel().ForAll(pid =>
{
   // do a task that either succeeds or fails
   // independently of other tasks
}
```

Then I want the end user to see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quartz ;)

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/